# Retaining NaN values after get_dummies in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df' like this -

```
Id    v1    v2
0     A     0.23
1     B     0.65
2     NaN   0.87
```

If I use

```
df1 = get_dummies(df)
df1
```

I get

```
Id    v1_A    v1_B    v2
0     1       0       0.23
1     0       1       0.65
2     0       0       0.87 .
```

How can I get the following efficiently?

```
Id    v1_A    v1_B    v2
0     1       0       0.23
1     0       1       0.65
2     NaN     NaN     0.87 .
```

I was using this initially, but it takes too long

```
import numpy as np    
dfv1 = df[[v1]]    #Slicing the v1 column
dfs = get_dummies(dfv1)    
dfsum = dfs.apply(np.sum, axis=1)    #Calculating row by row sum of dfs
for i in range(dfs.size):    #Iterating over the entire dataframe
    if dfsum.iloc[i]==0:     #and if the sum is zero for some 'i'
        dfs.iloc[i][:]==np.nan    #changing corresponding row to NaN
del df['v1']    #Deleting original column
df = pandas.concat([df, dfs], axis=1)    #Appending the new one
```

I am using Python 3.5.1 on Jupyter, and Pandas 0.18 . Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method #1 would be to use `v1`'s nans directly, without loops:

```
>>> df1 = pd.get_dummies(df)
>>> df1.loc[df.v1.isnull(), df1.columns.str.startswith("v1_")] = np.nan
>>> df1
   Id    v2  v1_A  v1_B
0   0  0.23   1.0   0.0
1   1  0.65   0.0   1.0
2   2  0.87   NaN   NaN
```

Method #2 would be to use the `dummy_na` argument to get us a column we could use:

```
>>> df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, dummy_na=True)
>>> df1
   Id    v2  v1_A  v1_B  v1_nan
0   0  0.23   1.0   0.0     0.0
1   1  0.65   0.0   1.0     0.0
2   2  0.87   0.0   0.0     1.0
>>> df1.loc[df1.v1_nan == 1, ["v1_A", "v1_B"]] = np.nan
>>> del df1["v1_nan"]
>>> df1
   Id    v2  v1_A  v1_B
0   0  0.23   1.0   0.0
1   1  0.65   0.0   1.0
2   2  0.87   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, method 1 works for me. Any hints how I could extend it for a similar dataframe with many columns like v1?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use a simple data frame as an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A'],[np.nan, 'B'], ['C', np.nan]])

>>> df1
     0    1
0    A    A
1  NaN    B
2    C  NaN
```

Then one-hot-encode it:

```
df1_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df1, dummy_na=True)

>>> df1_ohe
   0_A  0_C  0_nan  1_A  1_B  1_nan
0    1    0      0    1    0      0
1    0    0      1    0    1      0
2    0    1      0    0    0      1
```

Now get a subset of this data frame, containing only the NaN columns:

```
nan_df = df1_ohe.loc[:, df1_ohe.columns.str.endswith("_nan")]

>>> nan_df
   0_nan  1_nan
0      0      0
1      1      0
2      0      1
```

Finally, use a little regex and iterate over each row in the data frame and each NaN column.

If this position [row, NaN column] contains 1, then that position on the original data frame (before OHE) is a NaN.

Therefore, I use regex to identify the original columns "col_id" (i.e., 1_nan gives me 1, which is the column that contains NaN in the non-OHE data frame).

So I target all columns that contain that position (i.e., 1_A, 1_B and 1_nan) and replace their values with NaN.

```
pattern = "^([^_]*)_"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for index in df1_ohe.index:
    for col_nan in nan_df.columns:
        if df1_ohe.loc[index,col_nan] == 1:
            col_id = regex.search(col_nan).group(1)
            targets = df1_ohe.columns[df1_ohe.columns.str.startswith(col_id+'_')]
            df1_ohe.loc[index, targets] = np.nan
```

Giving me:

```
>>> df1_ohe
   0_A  0_C  0_nan  1_A  1_B  1_nan
0  1.0  0.0    0.0  1.0  0.0    0.0
1  NaN  NaN    NaN  0.0  1.0    0.0
2  0.0  1.0    0.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Finally, I remove the NaN columns from the OHE data frame

```
df1_ohe.drop(df1_ohe.columns[df1_ohe.columns.str.endswith('_nan')], axis=1, inplace=True)


>>> df1_ohe
   0_A  0_C  1_A  1_B
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0
2  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code